# Export a excel file witout any dialog+asp.net,c#

Tags: asp.net

I am exporting a excel file from "c:Test\data.xls" using the responce object
like:

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
```

it is opening a dialog box.But Now we don't need the dialog box.we want to directly open file without dialog.
Can any body help me out

Answer (score 1):

use

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + FileName + ";");
```

Whether it opens directly depends on client-side security settings to this might work but there is no guarantee...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching file to response you nee write it's content to response stream.

```
//Set the appropriate ContentType.
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; // not sure in content type
//Get the physical path to the file.
string filePath = @"c:Test\data.xls";
//Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
Response.WriteFile(filePath);
Response.End();
```

But also it depeneds on the client side settings.